# Can MyEtherWallet/Jaxx interact with a Mist generated Multisig wallet?

Tags: wallets, multisignature, myetherwallet, jaxx

I've created a 3 fo 5 multisig wallet using the Mist browser. The first account was created in Mist, but the rest were on different computers (some offline) and I just typed in the public addresses in Mist when assigning owners.

So, now I'm trying to send Ether to The DAO, and I can only get the original Mist account to sign the transaction. I can't seemd to understand if MyEtherWallet will let me "Approve" the transaction from the Contract... and Jaxx won't even let me sign an arbitrary message let alone import an ABI.

So far it looks like I'll need Mist on each Computer and mobile signing will have to wait...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using a multisig wallet contract requires that each address that was registered as a co-owner is able to call the wallet contract validate method.

Jaxx only supports ether transfer from an address to another but doesn't support contract method interactions. For now you have to use mist or any software that can interact with contracts as Geth or any other ethereum client.

Comment: So currently, If I create a multiSig contract wallet in Mist, there is no way I can import them to MyEtherWallet/Jaxx? so, all the co-owner accounts need to be on Mist in order to validate transactions?

Comment: @PrashantPrabhakarSingh nop, sorry.

Comment: @Nicolas Massart how does one do this? I mean how does one interact with an old Wallet Contract created in a very early version of mist or it's precursor "ethereum wallet" - I am searching everywhere for simple answers of how to do things like view balances, and transfer ERC tokens from it to a regular address.

Comment: @user3462143 have you tried MyEtherWallet ?